# How to create firebase admin user for authentication in java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase java based project with user authentication. I want to create an Admin user and allow admin to read/wite users verification/validation.

FYI, im Total firebase noob. and I have'nt found any meaningful resource on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "admin user" in Firebase. You will have to create the logic for that in your app. How to do this, depends on the logic of your app (and for example the Firebase features you use).

If you're using the Firebase Database, these are good places to start:

- The [Firebase Database documentation on user based security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security)
- This [gist about role based security](https://gist.github.com/sararob/331760829a9dcb4be3e7)
- Q: [how do I implement role based access control in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520615/how-do-i-implement-role-based-access-control-in-firebase)
- Q: [Firebase: set security rules depending on user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641184/firebase-set-security-rules-depending-on-user-roles)
- Blog post: [Implementing Roles in Firebase](http://curlybrackets.co/blog/2016/03/07/implementing-roles-in-firebase/)
- Most of the [top search results here](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=firebase+role+based+security)